# How can I see the code for data types?

Tags: c#, ilspy

I tried finding the code for specific data types like float, int and bool in c# using Ilspy, but wasn't able to. 
Is it possible to find the specific code used for these types in c# using Ilspy or any other way?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/ - it's all been open sourced.

Comment: Look for it in [dotnetframework.org](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/)

Comment: Some parts are visible in ILSpy (`GetHashCode` for example), other parts (the arithmetic operators for example) are directly supported by the processor, so they don't really have source code...

Comment: It highly depends on what you mean by "the code". These are special types that are implemented by a mixture of common metadata (`System.Int32`), some managed code, some unmanaged code and some logic in the jitter itself. While the source for all of these is available, there is no one single place that has all the details.

Comment: Some other parts (like the `[...]` of `string`) are marked as `MethodImplOptions.InternalCall` and have some corresponding C++ code hidden somewhere in the links given to you by mikeTheLiar and Pikoh

Comment: The C++ code for `MethodImplOptions.InternalCall` is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/master/src/classlibnative/bcltype)